# Wordpress ACF add div even

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been given the code below which uses Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields to create boxes on a page. I am looking to include a blank div before every even div produced e.g:

```
<div class="span2 team-'. $count .'"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div> <- inserted blank div needed
<div class="span2 team-'. $count .'"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div> <- inserted blank div needed
```

My current code below is producing the boxes, which I can't seem to work out how to count the div and input the blank div. I think this could be done with PHP or Jquery.

```
                    <?php
if ( get_field('team') )
{
echo '<div class="span6">';
echo '<div class="row">';
$count=0;
while ( has_sub_field('team') )
{
    echo '<div class="span2 team-'. $count .'"> ';
    echo '<a class="inline cboxElement" href="#inline_content-'. $count .'">';
    $personimage_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image_person'), 'why_img');
    echo '<img src="' . $personimage_url[0] . '">';
    echo '</a> ';
    echo '<div style="display:none"> ';
    echo '<div id="inline_content-'. $count .'" class="row"> ';
     echo '<div class="span10 about-area">';
     echo '<div class="contact_img">';
    $about_url =         wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image_person'), 'about_img');
    echo '<img src="' . $about_url[0] . '"></div>';
    if ( get_sub_field('name') ) echo '<span class="name">' .         get_sub_field('name') . '</span> ';
    if ( get_sub_field('about') ) echo '<span class="about">'.     get_sub_field('about') .'</span>';
    echo '</div><br style="clear: both;">';
    echo '<div id="lightbox">
<h1 id="site-title" class="span5"> <span> <a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website" rel="home">Website</a>         </span> </h1>
</div>';
    echo '</div> ';
    echo '</div> ';
    echo '<span class="contact_label">' . get_sub_field('name') .     '</span>';
    echo '</div> ';
    $count++;
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're echoing out your HTML within PHP rather than just closing/opening PHP tags? Must be a nightmare to maintain!

Comment: Atleast switch to http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php. It is really easy to make a typo in your code.

Comment: I think you don't need the modulo function, you can just print two divs for each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `modulus` operator along with your `count` variable to do this:

```
<?php
if ( get_field('team') )
{
echo '<div class="span6">';
echo '<div class="row">';
$count=0;
while ( has_sub_field('team') )
{

    echo '<div class="span2 team-'. $count .'"> ';
    echo '<a class="inline cboxElement" href="#inline_content-'. $count .'">';
    $personimage_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image_person'), 'why_img');
    echo '<img src="' . $personimage_url[0] . '">';
    echo '</a> ';
    echo '<div style="display:none"> ';
    echo '<div id="inline_content-'. $count .'" class="row"> ';
     echo '<div class="span10 about-area">';
     echo '<div class="contact_img">';
    $about_url =         wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image_person'), 'about_img');
    echo '<img src="' . $about_url[0] . '"></div>';
    if ( get_sub_field('name') ) echo '<span class="name">' .         get_sub_field('name') . '</span> ';
    if ( get_sub_field('about') ) echo '<span class="about">'.     get_sub_field('about') .'</span>';
    echo '</div><br style="clear: both;">';
    echo '<div id="lightbox">
<h1 id="site-title" class="span5"> <span> <a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website" rel="home">Website</a>         </span> </h1>
</div>';
    echo '</div> ';
    echo '</div> ';
    echo '<span class="contact_label">' . get_sub_field('name') .     '</span>';
    echo '</div> ';

    // Use modulo to see if $count is divisible by 2 (i.e. an even number)
    if ($count % 2 === 0)
    {
        // Insert blank div
        echo '<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>';
    }

    $count++;
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, when input into the PHP template it isn't showing anything. Also, I dont want it to replace even number div, I want it to input a blank div before an even.

Comment: I've updated the code to not skip the even divs. As for it not showing anything, I did a quick test page and it worked OK - are you getting any WordPress error messages?

Comment: Ok, it is rendering but not in the correct order: <div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-0"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-1”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-2”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-3”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-4”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-5”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-6”> </div>

Comment: That's outputting a blank before each even, do you mean the blank `div` that is output at the start?

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain it correctly in my example.  Im looking to have as: <div class="span2 team-0"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-1”> </div>

<div class="span2 team-2”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-3”> </div>

<div class="span2 team-4”> </div>
<div class="span2 team-blank even"> </div>
<div class="span2 team-5”> </div>

Comment: Moving the `if` condition to the end of the `while` statement will give you that layout. I've changed the code again to show this.

Comment: Why add the class `even` if you can style it with CSS with `:even` ?

Comment: I think you don't need the modulo function, you can just print two divs for each iteration

Comment: Styling with :even wouldn't work as every 3rd element needs styling. :nth-child(3n) would work. Modulo is needed if OP only wants the extra div for even team numbers only.